Is it reasonable that my human-habitable alternate universe look different?
In the story I am planning, I wanted to have two universes, one just like ours, in which humans evolved, and another that is sufficiently similar to our own that humans may survive, but in which differences in the laws of physics allow the Practicality of engine-mediated magic.  These two universes have been colliding periodically for millions of years at decreasing intervals, for increasingly longer durations, until they settle together effectively permanently.  Humans have been transplanted from our universe to that of Pandemonium where they have developed differently.
Since my story will involve humans from each universe being able to visit the other universe, I wanted to have differences that go beyond merely a separate evolution and social development.  While the stars and planets in each universe are going to be effectively very similar and co-located due to shared gravity, I wanted them to look different.
I was thinking that in Pandemonium (Earth's other-universe counterpart, save for its universe's somewhat different physical laws), that the sky and light from the sun could appear redder, and the sun could appear larger and dimmer, even though its distance and insolation energy would effectively be identical between the earths in the two universes, and plants would survive more or less equally well in either universe.
Because the wormholes between the universes will ensure that there can be only a small difference in composition between the suns in each, and the necessity for the viability of terrestrial life will enforce similar basic laws and constants, the two suns will be effectively identical in stage of life, composition, rate of atomic fusion etcetera.
Is this difference in humans' perception of the sun reasonable, or am I stretching the laws of physics a bit too far for terrestrial lifeforms' survivability in Pandemonium's universe?

Can you make the Sun appear larger and dimmer by actually giving it more mass, changing the stage of its life, etc?

@Allure No, the wormholes between universes will enforce a near identical composition between the two suns, and the necessity for terrestrial life to be possible in both will enforce a similar set of basic physical laws with identical rates of fusion etc.

Is Pandemonium's redder, or does it appear redder? If your laws of physics are slightly different, light likely behaves a little different, causing redshift to require less relative speed, for example.

@Joachim, It could be redder if a star of the same size and density could be redder without the universe becoming non-inhabitable by humans, or it could just appear larger and redder.

The Sun: making the Sun appear dimmer and redder is pretty easy: dust-up the atmosphere. Fine dust (like the one blow from over the Sahara to as far as Scotland) can make the Sun look almost blood red, and the sky orange, not just at dawn, but even at noon. It is harder to justify the Sun looking bigger, but can be done with an optical illusion. Maybe have a constant visible strip of atmospheric dust floating through the sky like almost a fake horizon. When the Sun dips close to the dust strip, you would get the same Ponzo Illusion you get when the Sun is near horizon: our brains get confused when something moves close to a horizontal line, and the "is this thing big and far away, or closer and small?" part of our visual cortex just assumes the thing is bigger than it actually is. You can test it yourself by looking (with safety goggles) at the Sun at Noon and Sundown. Downing Sun looks noticeably bigger, even though its not possible. You can even look at the Sun through a caliper and check for yourself that the disk is exactly the same size, and yet, your brain will insist that at sundown it is bigger, math be damned.
Can't say how the permanent dust cloud would interact with your magic, this is up to you. Maybe the dust IS the magic, or a side effect of worlds colliding. Maybe its not dust at all, but floating baby wormholes, to small for matter to pass, but big enough to disturb photons.
Other than that, a dust cloud of any type can either make the Pandemonium darker and hotter (if the dust has low albedo, which is likely if it reddens the air) or darker and cooler (if the dust is lighter shade and reflects more sunlight than it soaks.)
I would assume that a world called PANDEMONIUM of all things should be hotter though ;)
You can even have the causation be opposite: the Pandemonium is hot and dry for a completely different reason, this in turn keeps kicking up fine dust storms, which in turn redden the sky. Maybe Pandemonium is far further into Global Warming phase. Maybe the dust is hotboxing the planet, or maybe the dust is the only thing keeping the planet from turning into a scorched deathworld like Arrakis/Dune or Tatooine. Lots of options here, depending on how reflective the dust is.
A different thing that you need to consider, is that if the two worlds evolved semi-separately, and then every once in a while collide, allowing life to migrate between them, both worlds would experience dramatic mass extinction events, invasive species infestations, and pandemics.  If humans co-evolve on Earth and Padnemonium, then every time someone from Earth to Pandemonium there would be a high risk of them introducing Pandemonians to a new and exciting type of Influenza, Mumps, Plague or HIV. Inversely, Pandemonians would send their own diseases our way. And all of this is actually quite benign compared to various types of pests, weeds, fungi and bacteria crossing between world and causing ecosystem disasters in their new home. A bunch of Earth Rabbits could very well end up scouring a whole continent in the Pandemonium, and the common pandemonic squirp could easily wipe out every fish in the Atlantic.
This can either be acknowledged as a plot point, or you need a way to handwave it away.
